# Exposing a Swift variable in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, unity-game-engine

I am using a Swift class which uses a variable sharedInstance. When I am trying to use this variable in my Objective-C file, I am getting the error:

> No known class method for selector 'sharedInstance'

My Swift class:

```
class SpeakToMeForUnity : NSObject, SFSpeechRecognizerDelegate {

fileprivate var speechRecognizer : SFSpeechRecognizer?
fileprivate var recognitionRequest : SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest?
fileprivate var recognitionTask : SFSpeechRecognitionTask?
fileprivate var audioEngine : AVAudioEngine?

static let sharedInstance = SpeakToMeForUnity()

override fileprivate init() {
    super.init()

    self.speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "ja-JP"))!
    self.audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    self.speechRecognizer?.delegate = self
                            }
// Some other functions
}
```

Below is my Objective-C file:

```
#import <Speech/Speech.h>
#import "SpeakToMeForUnity-Swift.h"

extern "C"
{
    void _prepareRecording()
    {
        SpeakToMeForUnity *instance = [SpeakToMeForUnity sharedInstance];
        [instance prepareRecording];
    }

    void _recordButtonTapped()
    {
        SpeakToMeForUnity *instance = [SpeakToMeForUnity sharedInstance];
        [instance recordButtonTapped];
    }
}
```

I am using Swift 4 and Xcode 10.3.

Answer (score 2):

Normally to make Swift available in Objective-C you just need to import your swift module `#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"`, as you're doing.

If you need the swift code in the Objective-C header use `@class MySwiftClass;` or `@protocol MySwiftClass;`.

You can force some class or property to be accessible in Objective-C by adding the attribute `@objc`.

> Remember that `private` or `fileprivate` access level attributes will not be accessible unless you add the previous attribute.

Answer (score 2):

To expose things to ObjC, you need to mark them `@objc`. In this case you should add this before `class` and before the `static let`.

In previous versions of Swift, inheritance from `NSObject` automatically implied `@objc`, but that was removed, and it now needs to be explicit.